# Android xmlPullParser Exception Chunked stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I am getting an error wil parsing an XMl using the xmlPull parser.
The exception that i am getting is 
org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly

Can you please let me know the reason for the error and methods to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its caused by an old apache httpclient (its not able to handle chunked http requests correctly), but I currently don't know how to solve it on the client side.
You could write your own firmware with the new apache httpclient version, but this is ....
Another solution I saw is to setup a proxy between client and server which removes the chunked encoding (fiddler is able to do this)

(Perhaps you could force on the server side un-chunked responses ...)

Answer (score 0):

Could you be closing your AndroidHttpClient before you are finished reading your InputStream?